# Problem after copying text: inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:‭ not set up for use with LaTeX

Tags: errors, unicode, input-encodings

I have a LaTeX document, that can be compiled without any problems, but after copying some text into the document, I'm getting a huge amount of errors that say:

> ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:­ 
>   not set up for use with LaTeX.

I know that this kind of error is quite common, but in my case it is not caused by a single character, but the whole text (which is very long).

The text has been written in Abi Word and saved as UTF-8 encoded text file. The Texmaker Editor uses also UTF-8 encoding. I don't know what could be wrong with that copied text.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you add the whole line with the error?

Comment: There are many, many lines with the same error: _! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:‭ not set up for use with LaTeX.See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help_

Comment: I understand it. But if you faithfully copy and paste one of those lines from the log file, it's maybe possible to know which character is triggering the error. Add the line to your question rather than in a comment, please.

Comment: Try also adding before `\begin{document}` the instruction `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A0}{ }`

Comment: I have tried this command already, which I have found in another thread, but it didn't work. The evildoer seems to be a ":", but I don't know why that happens.

Comment: No, `\u8:` is a common prefix for this kind of errors.

Comment: as egreg requested earlier please add the complete lines with the first error message to your answer.

Comment: Thanks. The error occurs here: _! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:‭ not set up for use with LaTeX. See the inputenc package documentation for explanation. Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.95 wird in diesen Pufferspeicher geschrieben,‭
Your command was ignored.
Type I <command> <return> to replace it with another command,
or <return> to continue without it._  I didn't mean the ":" of the error message, but the ":" contained in the text, because some parts of the text are accepted, others are not accepted. The error might have to do with line breaks and smybols like ":".

Comment: When I copy one single word from the text to Latex, then the Latex document can be compiled, so it's sure that this problem is caused by only certain characters.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Unhappily `utf8.def` does not show the numerical representation for the missing Unicode character. The missing character `<char>` is shown directly in macro `\u8:<char>`. The following example adds the numerical information in the error message:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{stringenc}
\usepackage{pdfescape}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\UTFviii@defined}[1]{%
  \ifx#1\relax
    \begingroup
      % Remove prefix "\u8:"
      \def\x##1:{}%
      % Extract Unicode char from command name
      % (utf8.def does not support surrogates)
      \edef\x{\expandafter\x\string#1}%
      \StringEncodingConvert\x\x{utf8}{utf16be}% convert to UTF-16BE
      % Hexadecimal representation
      \EdefEscapeHex\x\x
      % Enhanced error message
      \PackageError{inputenc}{Unicode\space char\space \string#1\space
                              (U+\x)\MessageBreak
                              not\space set\space up\space
                              for\space use\space with\space LaTeX}\@eha
    \endgroup
  \else\expandafter
    #1%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
^^c2^^a0 % 7-bit input for U+00A0
\end{document}
```

Result:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:  (U+00A0)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

Comment: That's a neat feature! Is there a sensible place for it in some of your packages?

Comment: Thanks for that nice macro :-) It reveals the following characters:  \u8:‭ (U+202D) and \u8:‬ (U+202C). I have already found a solution by trial and error: I just copied the text from AbiWord to OpenOffice, saved it and then copied it to the Latex document. The document then compiled without any problems - for whatever reason. However, I would like to know what exactly caused that problem.

Comment: Perhaps you could also add some meaningful message if no sensible utf8 char is recognized (when people use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in a 8-bit document). Currently e.g. äü gives: `Unicode char \u8:äüÂ (U+)  not set up for use with LaTeX.`

Comment: @user1812379: These characters are `U+202D LEFT-TO-RIGHT OVERRIDE` and `U+202C POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING`. I assume your text always has left-to-right writing direction, then you can disable these Unicode characters by `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{202D}{}` and `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{202C}{}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Yes, my intention is to make a package and thanks for the hint that there might be malformed Unicode sequences.

Comment: Thanks. I have read about that here (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202C/index.htm), but I don't know what it exactly is. The DeclareUnicodeCharacter command maps the unwanted character to an in this case empty character?

Comment: @user1812379: These Unicode code points are not real characters with glyphs, they tell the text processor about writing directions. Package `inputenc` with driver file `utf8.def` makes the (≈ non-ASCII) characters active and `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` defines a meaning, in this case an empty macro. Thus they expand into nothingness rather being real characters with invisible glyph appearance.